# How websockets.onmessage is implemented in browsers Internals (i.e. Chrome) regarding concurrency (multi-threading) issues?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, internals

Websockets implementation in Javascript is as follows:

```
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { ... }
```

But what if the client is busy processing other stuff?

Is Javascript Websockets internals doing stuff in a separate thread or main UI thread (since Javascript is "mostly" not multi-threading)?

So if main UI thread is busy, will socket communication wait or browser will process that information in a separate thread? What about standards for this implementation?